# Align div background with that of its parent

Tags: html, css, html4

I would like to have a div with a background and inside it more divs with the illusion that their background applies some filter on the parent's background. As the support for filters is not quite here, I was thinking that I will create the filtered image and then set the `background-position` attribute of children in such a way that the backgrounds align with the parent. In jQuery, I could write something like:

```
$this.css('background-position', -$this.offset)
```

Is it possible to achieve this effect without JavaScript? I was able to get almost what I wanted by setting children background to `fixed`, but of course I do not want them to be fixed to viewport, I want it to be fixed to parent.

To give you a better idea, here is a quick mockup I put together in Gimp:

[image]

EDIT: I have created [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FB2Qp/3/), with `fixed` background.

Comment: +1. Good question. @martin could you create a JSFiddle for this..? It should attract more eyeballs then..

Comment: Just to be specific.. are you looking for a HTML4 only solution? As HTML5 does offer filters that could do what is described above..

Comment: Let's say it is HTML4 solution. OTOH, even HTML5 filters have their limits. If the second image is some fancy Photoshop filter, like Edge detect, or Posterize, you would have hard time replicating that look with CSS filters. Besides it can be a performance hit, while loading two images is simple and gives me complete control over what user sees.

Comment: @KentPawar what filters? I would be interested in that; EDIT: I see, those available in webkit nightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do that using only CSS. **Save yourself some time, and look into alternative solution**

see also:

- [CSS background-position fixed to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811589/css-background-position-fixed-to-parent)
- [background image position fixed to parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323281/background-image-position-fixed-to-parent-element)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a png picture with a transperancy (and this blue-purple color), and give to the children this image as background-image.
Then you need to center the children with margin:auto.

It's should work!
Hope I understood you correctly.. :)

Sorry about my poor English..
Good luck!

Comment: You can also give to the children background-color and give him opacity..
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: Obviously, this is what I would do, if I knew exactly how many children divs I have and where. However, I am looking for a more generic solution. Imagine that the text in the divs is some news feed: I cannot create custom background for each new div.

Comment: Changing background color transparency only gives me color tinges. I want to have a more complex filter (think inverse, or hue shift or something like that).

Comment: I dont understand, why do u need to know how much children do you have?!
Create a 1X1 png background and use background repeat...

Comment: Or u can also use background-size:100% (only in css3)

Comment: My effect is not a simple transparency/tinge/filter thingie. I thought you meant to say I should create a specific background for each child div. That would of course work, but I can't do it for the reasons outlined above.